# Microsoft Sync Framework Change Detection Only

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-sync-framework

I am working with the Microsoft Sync Framework version 2.1 in C# and am trying to do what I believe to be a simple task. I would like to use the framework to detect changes to a folder full of files since the last run. I do not need to synchronize/replicate the folder to any destination, I merely want to know which files were added, modified, and removed since the last run. I believe the metadata file associated with the FileSyncProvider keeps track of this data, but I am having a hard time figuring out how to collect the changes, as all examples I have found show how to synchronize between two directories.

Is there a way to get a list of changes? Any guidance is appreciated.

Best,
Brett

Answer (score 0):

you dont have to explicitly read the metadata, the API supports explicit change detection. have a look at the sample [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt763483.aspx)